# Can I share my app script library to another account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, libraries

I create Library in my app script and share it by another spread sheet and work fine.
now I share this spread sheet by another google account but not working in the library section give me error: `You do not have access to library *********, used by your script, or it has been deleted`.

I try to add the Script ID in another account to find library but give me this error: `You do not have access to library *******, used by your script, or it has been deleted.`

Any help about that pleas.

Answer (score 2):

You need to share your Library (or your script and sheet if it is a bound script) to your users from [script.google.com](https://script.google.com/home). This should appear when you click on the menu option (...) beside your deployed library/script.

[image]

This should give other accounts permission to access your Library.

**Reference:**

[Libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#new-editor_1)

Comment: I Try A lot of method I do this but I need to share just library without sheet, because I don't want the other user see my code

Comment: Then you have to refactor your code so that it functions as a standalone script without the need to bind it to a spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes I see this method but the big problem in the app script is how to hide your code if you give that to customers

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't "blackbox" your library, as you need at least **view-level access** to include a library to a project. You can check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#new-editor_1) for details.

Comment: Okay I try to read it, thanks

Comment: @CMB isn't this library blackboxed? https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/1ReeQ6WO8kKNxoaA_O0XEQ589cIrRvEBA9qcWpNqdOP17i47u6N9M5Xh0/12

Answer (score 1):

If you want one or more methods of your script to not be visible (nor usable) to your library users, you can end the name of the method with an underscore. For example, myPrivateMethod_().

Resource scoping.
There are two types of resources: Shared and Not-Shared.
[image: Shared resource]

[image: Not-Shared resource]

Please read this for more details - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries